# Solving Four-Variable System of Inequalities with Solveset

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve a system of inequalities with four variables using SymPy solveset. I am very new to both Python and SymPy. Basically my hope was that this code would output the ranges of values that each of these four variables can take such that all elements in the set of inequalities are true.

```
from sympy import solveset
from sympy import Symbol

e = Symbol('e')
hA = Symbol('hA')
hB = Symbol('hB')
ed = Symbol('ed')


equations = [((1-ed)*(1-e))/hA>0, ((1-ed)*(1-e))/hA<.03, (ed*e+(1-ed)-e)/hB>.03/.97, e>0, e>1, hA>0, hB>0, hB<1, ed>0, ed<1]

variables = [e,hA,hB,ed]

solveset(equations,variables)
```

When I run this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    solveset(inequalities,variables)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solveset.py", line 1658, in solveset
    raise ValueError("%s is not a valid SymPy expression" % f)
ValueError: [(1 - e)*(1 - ed)/hA > 0, (1 - e)*(1 - ed)/hA < 0.03, 
(e*ed - e - ed + 1)/hB > 0.0309278350515464, e > 0, 
e > 1, hA > 0, hB > 0, hB < 1, ed > 0, ed < 1] is not a valid SymPy expression
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Currently I think solveset only works with single equations or inequalities. The solve function can handle multiple equations or inequalities but only works with univariate inequalities. I recommend opening an issue on github and explaining what you would want the output to be in this case.

Comment: Thanks Oscar for the help!

Comment: Did you mean for the constraint on `e` to be `e < 1`?